# Debugging hadoop applications

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I tried printing out values using System.out.println(), but they won't appear on the console. How do i print out the values in a map/reduce application for debugging purposes using Hadoop?

Thanks,
Deepak.

Comment: Refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235343/debugging-hadoop-in-eclipse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The page @SquareCog points to is a very good source of information on debugging a MapReduce job once you are running it on a cloud.

Before you reach that point though you should consider writing unit tests for your mappers and reducers, so you can verify that the basic logic works. If you are interested in unit tests to test drive your map and reduce logic check out [mrunit](http://archive.cloudera.com/docs/mrunit/index.html), which works in a similar fashion to JUnit.

Comment: @SquareCog - My bad, i just assumed I knew which page you'd linked to. Its a good source of information :+)

Answer (score 5):

Lines printed out using System.out.println and System.err.println go to the logs that Hadoop writes on a per-job basis. You can view them using the web UI by clicking through to individual tasks.

See this blog post from Cloudera for a lot of advice on testing and debugging Hadoop jobs: http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2009/07/advice-on-qa-testing-your-mapreduce-jobs/

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add, that you can use `Counters` [Hadoop JavaDoc](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Counter.html) for debugging as well. E.g. if you want to check, how often a certain line in your program is passed.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println is not directed to the terminal but rather written to the logs files. Log files are situated in your Hadoop directory by default. So you can type in the terminal
`cat /hadoop-homedirectory/logs/userlogs/jobID/attemptID/stdout` 
 You can also access your via the web interface. Type ip:50070/logs/userlogs.

Answer (score 0):

If you use MRUnit & ApprovalTests it is very easy to print out the process of a map reduce job. 
There's a video on it here: http://t.co/leExFVrf

For example the code

```
HadoopApprovals.verifyMapReduce(new WordCountMapper(), 
                             new WordCountReducer(), 0, "cat cat dog");
```

Will produce the output:

```
[cat cat dog] 
-> maps via WordCountMapper to ->
(cat, 1) 
(cat, 1) 
(dog, 1)

-> reduces via WordCountReducer to ->
(cat, 2) 
(dog, 1)
```