# Debugging hadoop in eclipse

Tags: debugging, hadoop, mapreduce

Is it possible to debug Hadoop's source code in Eclipse?I'm not asking about the map reduce tasks. I want to see which part of the Hadoop source code is responsible for scheduling the map reduce tasks and how it works. Is there any mechanism by which it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can download Hadoop project and integrate it to your eclipse, and use F5 or F6 to debug.
You have different mode of debugging in eclipse:

1. F5 : Step by Step debugging
2. F6 : Skips loops and Subroutines
3. F7 : Skips the loop or subroutine and returns to the last cursor point.
4. F8 : Execute and come out of debugging

Or you can try yourself to understand the workflow by following step by step, you can begin from your `run()` method in your main.

To answer your question: who does schedule the map task? 
[image]

As you can see in this schema, files are divided by the `InputFormat` class into fixed-size pieces called InputSplits. Each split is then given to a mapper, which is a node that was assigned a map task.

The same `InputFormat` class also provides a `RecordReader` responsible for parsing the split and extracting records.Each record is passed to a map function as a (key, value) pair. So the `Mapper` class is the one who call `map` methods.

Here is the workflow of the wordcount example:

[image]

Where the [FileInputFormat](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-737/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileInputFormat.java) is an abstract class that extends the abstract class [InputFormat](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-737/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/InputFormat.java#InputFormat), and the [TextInputFormat](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-737/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/TextInputFormat.java?av=f) extends the `FileInputFormat` class.

Comment: How is the integration of Hadoop in Eclipse done?I followed the steps specified in Hadoop wiki and imported the projects into the eclipse workspace. Which project should I run first?

Comment: You can clone it from GitHub `https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common`, I don't know which projects you imported in your eclipse and which tuto you followed. This [one](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EclipseEnvironment) is good I think. You can import all projects then use what you want, it depends from the version of hadoop you want to use(MapReduce v1 or yarn MRv2)

Comment: I imported all the projects to Eclipse. Now, which project should I run?

Comment: Did you create your own project?

Comment: You mean a map reduce job?My intention is to find the point where the master assigns the job to the nodes.I want to replicate these tasks and have a different job id for each task.Is it possible to do all of this through debugging?Can I find all these steps using a local Hadoop setup?

Comment: In your main method you submit your MapReduce job through `Job.submit()` , you can see [submit()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-320/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.java#Job.submit%28%29) method  in the Job class, you will see that a method [submitJobInternal(conf)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-320/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient.java#JobClient.submitJobInternal%28org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf%29) is called

Comment: The jobId is created in this method.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EclipseEnvironment) are instructions from Apache Hadoop documentation. I haven't tried them out, but the instructions are good enough to get started.